# Getting "object expected" error when using a variable containing a string as an argument for getElementById()

Tags: javascript, setinterval, getelementbyid

I'm doing an animation of 5 bugs flying randomly around the screen and bouncing off the sides. I made a function to do the animation for each bug. This is part of the function. The bugName variable contains the string "bugOne" when I pass it to getElementById(). When I use this code, I get an object expected error for this line.

```
 if (xDirection == "right" && xPosition > (widthMax - document.getElementById(bugName).width - flySpeed))
 xDirection = "left";
```

When I use this code instead, there is no syntax error (though the animation still doesn't work correctly for some reason).

```
 if (xDirection == "right" && xPosition > (widthMax - document.getElementById("bugOne").width - flySpeed))
     xDirection = "left";
```

How do I pass `bugName` to `getElementById()` without getting a syntax error?

This is how "bugOne" got into bugName. I'm deleting some code and only showing the basics.

I called it from the body onload event handler.

```
<body onload="flyVar=setInterval('setBug(\'bugOne\')', 30);">
```

So that called this function in the document head.

```
    function setBug(bugName) {
        flyBug(bugName);

}
```

And that called this function which is also in the document head.

```
function flyBug(bugName) {

    if (bugName == "bugOne") {
        flySpeed = 5;
        xPosition = 0;
        yPosition = 100;
        xDirection = "right";
        yDirection = "up";

     if (xDirection == "right" && xPosition > (widthMax - document.getElementById(bugName).width - flySpeed))
         xDirection = "left";
}
```

Comment: Show us how you got `"bugOne"` into `bugName`. And maybe try a `console.log(bugName)` to see what you're actually doing.

Comment: Well I know for a fact that bugName does actually contain "bugOne" because I did window.alert() to see if it contains it. But ok I'll show how it got in there.

Comment: Why are you passing a `string` to `setInterval`?

Comment: I'm passing a function called setBug to setInterval and I'm passing the string to setBug.

Comment: I suggest you use some alerts throughout the calling functions to test that `bugName` is being propogated through correctly at each point. Somewhere in the chain, it is not. Stick `alert(bugName);` at the beginning of each function and see what you end up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `setInterval()` doesn't directly support including parameters (I can't test this currently, but [I believe Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) where found the following:

> ### Callback arguments
>
> If you need to pass an argument to your callback function, but need it to work in Internet Explorer, which
>   doesn't support sending additional parameters (neither with
>   setTimeout() or setInterval()) you can include this IE-specific
>   compatibility code which will enable the HTML5 standard parameters
>   passage functionality in that browser for both timers just by
>   inserting it at the beginning of your scripts.
>
> [...example code...]
>
> Another possibility is to use an anonymous function to call your
>   callback, but this solution is a bit more expensive. Example:
>
> ```
>  var intervalID = setInterval(function() { myFunc("one", "two", "three"); }, 1000);
> ```
>
> Yet another possibility is to use function's bind. Example:
>
> ```
>  var intervalID = setInterval(function(arg1) {}.bind(undefined, 10), 1000);
> ```

So, I believe you can correct this behavior by changing your onload call as follows:

```
<body onload="flyVar=setInterval(function() { setBug('bugOne'); }, 30);">
```

Comment: I got a "invalid character" error for that body onload code you suggested. I'll try the anonymous function.

Comment: @user2234760 That came from the `\'` characters. I just copied that from your code and didn't think it through, but since we're converting this to an anonymous function, there's no need to escape the quotes (and doing so would make it invalid). I edited that out.

Comment: Actually, I don't really understand what the anonymous function is doing, when I look at it more closely. This is an assignment for a javascript 1 class so the instructor doesn't assume we'd know something like that. I moved the setInterval to the setBugs() function and called the setBugs function from body onLoad. That seems to work without giving a syntax error. The animation still doesn't work though.

Comment: Debugging the animation is going to be an entirely separate issue from getting the ID to pass into the function.

Comment: My guess is that you're not ever actually moving the dom element. The code you show here only checks some values of width against other variables. There has to be something that actually changes the position of the bug's dom element (presumably by adjusting some css position values).

Comment: Yeah the animation doesn't even move. But I copied the animation code exactly from an animation of a bouncing ball that bounces all over the page.